# Can 422215686281216 be expressed as the sum or difference of two fifth powers?

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

I have a large integer, 422215686281216.  I am looking for two fifth powers  which when added together, or subtracted from one another, equal this number.  How can I tell whether an integer  is the sum , or difference,  of two fifth powers ?

Answer (score 8):

You can show that sums and differences of two fifth powers cannot be congruent to $3$ modulo $11$.

Then note that your number is congruent to $3$ modulo $11$.

Conclude that you cannot write your number as a sum or difference of two fifth powers.

Added: Oh, so many opinions and helpful comments.  To clarify, I merely calculated sums and differences of fifth powers modulo $2, 3, 4,$ etc. until I found a modulus for which not all congruence classes were possible.  This happened to be $11$, and it just happened that one class left out, $3$, was the class of the given number.  This is a standard method for treating these sums-of-powers questions.  For further reading, take a look at most any introductory number theory text (let me know if you would like a more specific reference).

Comment: Why $3$ and $11$? Does this fit in a more general statement?

Comment: Possible values of a difference of $5$'th powers mod $11$ are $0, 1, 2, 9, 10$.  $11$ is the smallest modulus for which not everything is a possible value.

Comment: It's a good idea to try $11$ because $\phi(11)=10$ so $a^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ for all $a$, and (since $11$ is prime) $a^{5} \equiv \pm 1$ for all $a$. If $11$ didn't work (for example, if the number were divisible by $11$) then we could try other numbers $n$ such that $\phi(n)$ is a small multiple of $5$, such as $25$ or $31$.

Comment: Matthew, worth editing in that the possible values of $x^5$ are $0,1,-1 \pmod {11}$

Comment: @RobArthan Why? That's a pretty common approach to these types of problems.

Comment: A  very good answer.   Thank You Matthew  Conroy.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks, Rob!

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the note, Wlll.  I didn't use that fact explicitly here myself, as I just used a short piece of code to check until success.  I'm in a rather brute force phase these days. Cheers!

Comment: +1: your answer is now very helpful - it wasn't when I downvoted it.

Comment: @RobArthan Thanks, Rob!

Answer (score 4):

Here's something you could try if Matthew Conroy's trick didn't work.

More generally, suppose you have a positive integer $N$ and you want to write $N = x^5 - y^5$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers (this includes a sum of $5$'th powers if you take $y$ to be negative).  Note that 
$$ N = (x - y)(x^4 + x^3 y + x^2 y^2 + x y^3 + y^4)$$ 
so $x - y$ must be one of the (positive or negative) divisors of $N$.  Enumerate all divisors of $N$ (which you can do from the prime factorization); for each such divisor $d$, check whether the polynomial $(Y+d)^5 - Y^5 - N$ has an integer root.  If it does (say $r$), then $y = r$, $x = r+d$ is a solution.  If none of these has an integer root, it is not possible to write
$N$ as a sum or difference of $5$'th powers.

Comment: Excellent Answer.   Thanks very much  Robert Israel.