# Can 2140138088471960538384538519958130596908 be expressed as the sum, or difference, of three fifth powers?

Tags: number-theory, computational-mathematics

I have a large integer, 2140138088471960538384538519958130596908 , with 40 digits. I am looking for three fifth powers which when added together, or subtracted from one another, equal this number. This large integer is congruent to 9 ( mod 11 ) . Any ideas on how to make a start on this problem ?

Comment: Unless you have a definite algorithm to do this by hand, maybe using some nice computer will be handy.

Comment: If someone has wolfram alpha premium, maybe they could give it a go

Comment: Knowing the source of the number would be helpful. In particular, if this is a textbook problem, then perhaps you could mention some of the techniques covered for tackling these kinds of problems.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe the problem has a solution?  The only fifth powers $\bmod {11}$ are $0,1,10$ so this can be $0-1-1$ or $10-1\pm0$  The fifth root of three times your number is about $9.15E7$ so you only have to check numbers that large.  The $\bmod 11$ computation eliminates all but $1/20$ of the combinations.  Maybe you can try some other moduli and make a greater reduction to make a computer search feasible.

Comment: Is the question 'can this happen' or 'how can this happen'?. For instance, you've already noted the number's congruence class mod 11, which suggests that you understand some of the constraints involved. More generally, $x^5 \bmod n$ will cover a relatively small number of congruence classes if $5|\phi(n)$; for instance, mod $31$ the fifth powers are $0,\pm 1, \pm 5, \pm 6$, etc.

Comment: I don't know for sure that this problem has a solution.  But based on the work of Noam Elkies ( Harvard number theorist) , I believe, that this integer has "a high probability" of being expressed as  a sum , or difference, of three  fifth powers.

Comment: Googling the 40-digit number gives only 1 result, this post.

Comment: The "or difference" part is redundant; after all, if $n$ is a fifth power of an integer, then so is $-n$. Now, the questions of this kind are tricky, and we don't know the answers to some of those that seem to be way more elementary. For example, is 33 a sum of _three cubes_ (possibly negative)?

Answer (score 3):

Well, your number $N =2140138088471960538384538519958130596908$ is $$N=282508861^5-282441633^5 + 0$$ which I'm sure you were aware of but might have mentioned. In particular, if you're hoping for a second solution, this rules out any possible approach that takes the equation modulo $25$ or whatever and finds a contradiction.

Aside from that, well, there's an infinite search space, and the [largest known solutions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation5thPowers.html) to $a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5=e^5$ or $a^5+b^5+c^5=d^5+e^5$ are orders of magnitude smaller, so I'm not too optimistic. I did search for other solutions using one small fifth power, and got nowhere.

(Can you explain how you chose $282508861$ and $282441633$?)

Comment: Great! How much time was taken for computer search?

Comment: I gave up after an hour.

Comment: I mean the computer search for the solution $282508861^5-282441633^5 + 0$

Comment: Oh, once you somehow decide to consider that possibility, Mathematica can tell you the answer in about a second with  `Solve[x^5 + y^5 == 2140138088471960538384538519958130596908, {x, 
  y}, Integers]`. As mentioned in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2219987/383078), it's a finite problem.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: I made a small edit.